# php variable array name

Tags: php, variables

I got the following class and I want to know if it is possible to use a variable array name.

```
class Ajax{
    private $method;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->method = '$_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
}
```

So basically the $method variable should either contain the POST or GET method, next question is also if it is smart to use a reference here?

My first thought was:

```
$this->method = '$_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$this->metod =& $$this->method;
```

But that is not working.

Thanks for reading and help, much appreciation.

Comment: What do you want? Do you means pass the `$_POST` or `$_GET` to `$this->method`?

Comment: @xdazz check the comment I posted on the first answer :) Thanks for comment anyway.

Comment: $this->method will contain $_POST or $_GET
but it is not same as Global varible
even if you are refernce then it wil reference to string'$_POST' or $_GET

Comment: @Poonam also check the comment I posted on the first answer for my idea of this class.

Comment: When do you call the Ajax class? Either you catch every request in an index.php file and then decide what do or you can save the request method and pass the type when initiating the ajax class: $ajax = new Ajax($type);

Comment: @busypeoples It is MVC, it's an ajax controller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do

```
If ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    $this->method = $_GET;
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $this->method = $_POST;
}
```

If you want to directly work, then

```
$this->method = ${'_'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']};
```

OR you can just use the `$_REQUEST` (although it is not very good to use it)

```
$this->method = $_REQUEST;
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that one out, just wanted to know if it was possible if I could use it without the IF statement, gonna use this anyway. Do you know if it a good idea to use $this->method =& $_GET, so a reference or not?

Comment: The reference is not necessary.

Comment: I know it is not necessary, but would it be smart to use a reference else we got the data twice in memory right?

Comment: no,won't be twice, php use copy on write, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want something like

```
    $this->method = $$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

this being a "[variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)" (note the double $$). However, please don't do this. variable variables make for difficult-/impossible-to-debug code.

Comment: My idea is to create a ajax controller, with 3 variables, 1. json, 2. errors, 3. method. Once an action of the controller is called, we use whitelist validation, using the method variable that points to the request array, then if the validation pass, we set the json variable, finally the destructor of the class does echo json_encode($this->json). So than we have a nice solid ajax class using whitelist validation in a simple way :)

Comment: Ain't working it isn't pointing to the POST or GET array. When I print out $this->method it will return NULL while the POST definatly contained data.

Comment: That's why I said "something like". This'll evaluate to "POST", not "_POST", so you're not really assigning the _post data array.

Answer (score 1):

try to get it like this:

`$this->method = ${'_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']};`